# At which point occurs template Instantiation binding?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, name-binding, template-instantiation

This code is from "C++ programming language" by Bjarne Stroustrup (C.13.8.3 Point of Instantiation Binding)

```
template <class T>
void f(T value)
{
    g(value);
}

void g(int v);

void h()
{
    extern g(double);
    f(2);
}
```

And he mentions:

> Here, the point of instantiation for f() is just before h(), so
>   the g() called in f() is the global g(int) rather than the local
>   g(double). The definition of ‘‘instantiation point’’ implies that a
>   template parameter can never be bound to a local name or a class
>   member.

```
void h()
{
    struct X {}; // local structure
    std::vector<X> v; // error: can't use local structure as template parameter
}
```

My questions are:

1. Why should the first code work? `g()` is declared later, and I really get an error with G++ 4.9.2 that `g` isn't declared at that point.
2. *extern g(double)* - how this works? since return value doesn't matter in case of function overloading, then we can miss it in forward declarations?
3. *the point of instantiation for f() is just before h()* - why? isn't it logical that it'll get instantiated when `f(2)` is being called? Right where we call it, whence `g(double)` will be in scope already.
4. *The definition of ‘‘instantiation point’’ implies that a template parameter can never be bound to a local name or a class member* - Has this changed in C++14? I'm getting error with C++(G++ 4.9.2), but don't get error with C++14(G++ 4.9.2).

Comment: "In 1985, the first edition of The C++ Programming Language was released, which became the definitive reference for the language, as **there was not yet an official standard**." [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B#History) So it didn't change between `C++11` and `C++14`. It changed between "pre-standardization" and standardization.

Comment: Check 14.6.4.1 [temp.point] for the rules

Comment: also search for two phase name lookup

Comment: @bolov I'm reading third edition (1997).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

"In 1985, the first edition of The C++ Programming Language was released, which became the definitive reference for the language, as **there was not yet an official standard**." [wiki C++ History](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B#History) So it didn't change between C++11 and C++14. I can assume (and please take this with a grain of salt) it changed between "pre-standardization" and standardization. Maybe someone who knows better the history of C++ can shed more light here.

As for what actually happens:

---

First let's get out of the way the simple one:

```
extern g(double);
```

This is invalid C++. Historically, unfortunately C allowed omission of type. In C++ you have to write `extern void g(double)`.

---

Next, let's ignore the `g(double)` overload to answer your first question:

```
template <class T>
void f(T value)
{
    g(value);
}

void g(int v);

int main()
{
    f(2);
}
```

In C++ there is the infamous two phase name lookup:

- In the first phase, at the template definition, all [non-dependent names](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name) are resolved. Failure to do so is a hard error;
- Dependent names are resolved in phase two, at the template instantiation.

The rules are a bit more complicated, but that is the gist of it.

`g` is dependent on template parameter `T` so it passes the first phase. That means that if you never instantiate `f`, the code compiles just fine. At the second phase `f` is instantiated with `T = int`. `g(int)` is now searched, but not found:

> ```
> 17 : error: call to function 'g' that is neither visible in the template definition nor found by argument-dependent lookup
> g(value);
> ^
> 24 : note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'f<int>' requested here
> f(2);
> ^
> 20 : note: 'g' should be declared prior to the call site
> void g(int v);
> ```

In order for an arbitrary name `g` to pass with flying colors we have a few options:

1. Declare `g` previously:

```
void g(int);

template <class T>
void f(T value)
{
    g(value);
}
```

2. bring `g` in with `T`:

```
template <class T>
void f(T)
{
    T::g();
}

struct X {
   static void g();
};

int main()
{
    X x;
    f(x);
}
```

3. Bring `g` in with `T` via ADL:

```
template <class T>
void f(T value)
{
    g(value);
}

struct X {};

void g(X);

int main()
{
    X x;
    f(x);
}
```

These of course change the semantics of the program. They are meant to illustrate what you can and cannot have in a template.

---

As for why doesn't ADL find `g(int)`, but finds `g(X)`:

> § 3.4.2 Argument-dependent name lookup [basic.lookup.argdep]
>
> 3. For each argument type T in the function call, there is a set of zero or more associated namespaces and a set of zero or more
>      associated classes to be considered [...]:
>
>    - If T is a fundamental type, its associated sets of namespaces and classes are both empty.
>    - If T is a class type (including unions), its associated classes are: the class itself; the class of which it is a member, if any; and
>        its direct and indirect base classes. Its associated namespaces are
>        the namespaces of which its associated classes are members. [...]

---

And finally we get to why `extern void g(double);` inside main is not found: first of all we showed that `g(fundamental_type)` is found [iff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_and_only_if) it is declared prior to the `f` definition. So let's make it `void g(X)` inside `main`. Does ADL find it?

```
template <class T>
void f(T value)
{
    g(value);
}

struct X{};


int main()
{
  X x;
  void g(X);

  f(x);
}
```

No. Because it does not reside in the same namespace as `X` (i.e. global namespace) ADL can't find it.

Proof that `g` is not in global

```
int main()
{
  void g(X);

  X x;
  g(x); // OK
  ::g(x); // ERROR
}
```

> 34 : error: no member named 'g' in the global namespace; did you mean
>   simply 'g'?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have two question. 1. Why in first example `g` is a non-dependent? It's dependent from T (in this case int), with ADL it may be found in the namespace T is defined (for built in types namespace is supposed to be the global namespace, as far as I know). 2. With your logic, why `f(x)` works, but `f(2)` doesn't work with ADL?

Comment: @user1289: `f(2)` doesn't work with ADL because `2` is `int`, which is a fundamental type, and "1) For arguments of fundamental type, the associated set of namespaces and classes is empty" (See 3.9.1 Fundamental types [basic.fundamental])

Comment: @AndyG "The binding of dependent names is done by looking at the names in the namespace of an argument of a dependent call (global functions are considered in the namespace of built-in types" - this is from the same book.

Comment: @user1289: But `int` doesn't even bring in global functions. See bolov's part about declaring `g` before the template. Also, I think you should read a more recent book. You're asking C++14 questions using a book that was published before the C++03 standard.

Comment: I didn't found "For arguments of fundamental type, the associated set of namespaces and classes is empty" in documentation. Although, as you mentioned, f(2) doesn't compile for me, and f(x) compiles.

Comment: @user1289 you were right. `g` is dependent. But as far as I can tell, ADL works for user defined types only.

Comment: @user1289 found and updated about ADL, which is basically what AngyG said.